# Mongoose array to array search function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making an array to array search function. I have a schema which looks like this:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  pieces: Array,
  category: Schema.ObjectId
});
```

The `pieces` field is an array of the `title` field but it has been split into pieces with `title.split(' ');`.

So if the title looks like this: `Lorem ipsum doler sit amet` the pieces looks like this: `[ 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'doler', 'sit', 'amet' ]`

Now I got this search function that where I split the search input as well which I want to check against the `pieces` field in order to find the best results.
If I search for `Lorem doler amet` it becomes `[ 'Lorem', 'doler', 'amet' ]`.

The way I'm trying to do this is through this code:

```
var searchString = req.body.searchString;
Post
 .find({})
 .where('pieces').in(searchString.split(' ')) // The pieces must have ALL of the items from splitted searchString.
 .limit(30)
 .select('-_id -_v -pieces')
 .exec(function (err, posts) {
   // Do stuff
});
```

But it does not seem to work at all. Any clues on how I can make such a search function with Mongoose?

To simplify what I'm trying to do:

`check if 
  [ 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'doler', 'sit', 'amet' ] 
    contains ALL of 
  [ 'Lorem', 'doler', 'amet' ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe what you looking for is the [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator. Your mongoose code should be as follows:

```
var searchString = req.body.searchString;
Post
 .find({})
 .where('pieces').all(searchString.split(' '))
 .limit(30)
 .select('-_id -_v -pieces')
 .exec(function (err, posts) {
   // Do stuff
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to perform a query against an array field that must contain all of a specified set of elements.

In Mongoose, you can do this using [`Query#all`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-all) as:

```
Post
 .find({})
 .where('pieces').all(searchString.split(' '))
 .limit(30)
 .select('-_id -_v -pieces')
 .exec(function (err, posts) {
   // Do stuff
});
```